# How to read just the first column of each row of a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

How to read just the first column of each row of a CSV file in Python?

My data is something like this:

```
1 abc    
2 bcd    
3 cde
```

and I only need to loop trough the values of the first column.

Also, when I open the csv File in calc the data in each row is all in the same cell, is that normal?

Comment: Are the columns separated by a blank?

Comment: Given that there is a standard module for [CSV handling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) - what is the problem exactly?

Comment: In what way is it comma separated values?

Comment: @PeterWood It's fairly common to find `csv` files which use different delimiters. about 80% of the `csv` files I come across are tab, space or pipe delimited. Even had a couple which ended up being xml.

Answer (score 5):

```
import csv
with open(file) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    for i in reader:
        print i[0]
```

**OR**

change the delimter to space if necessary.

```
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
```

without csv module,

```
import csv
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.split()[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

To get just the first column as a list:

```
with open('myFile.csv') as f:
    firstColumn = [line.split(',')[0] for line in f]
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to simply do a `line in f` instead of doing `f.readlines()` edited accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted a version of the edit that is a definite improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.izip` to crate a generator contains the columns and use `next` to get the first column.Its more efficient if you have a large data and you want to refuse of multi-time indexing!

```
import csv
from itertools import izip
with open('ex.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
     print next(izip(*spamreader))
```

Answer (score 0):

for the second part of your question:

when opening csv-documents in LibreOffice Calc (openoffice should work the same way) I get a Dialog where I am asked a few things about that document, like charakter encoding and as well the type of separator. If you select "space", it should work. You have a preview at the bottom of this dialog.